# Can I get back to the old alt+tab switcher in Jólnir?

Tags: window-management, window-manager

For me this new alt+tab is less productive since I constantly have to check what is inside another window while having one window fixed on the top of the workspace. Is it possible to have it back? Elementary OS have always been unique in many ways and made me more productive than on any other distro, but this brings it close to the level of almost any other distro I can think of.